# Can I ask for the "identification" of a word depending on a meaning?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions, asking-questions

Basically, I'm thinking about the behaviour of someone I know, and something tells me there's a word to qualify that behaviour. However, I don't seem to remember any word that would suit.

Can I ask for that kind of question here?

I'm thinking I already stumbled on such question in the Hot Network Question, but I can't remember if it was on site site or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests). Please read our [guidelines for such questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

IMO the most important things to do are to provide a sentence you want to use the word in and provide any words you have discounted as unsuitable, and why they are unsuitable, so that people trying to answer have good insight into your thought process.

Comment: Thanks. The more I'm thinking, the more I realise I'd better search up in a dictionary than ask a question, since it's more of a curiosity than anything else.